# Trying to resolve mysqli_real_escape_string error

Tags: php, mysqli

I try to stop SQL_injection with this function. But I wonder why I get this error?

```
define('DB_HOST', 'localhost');
define('DB_USER', 'root');
define('DB_PASSWORD', '');
define('DB_DATABASE', 'cms');

$link = mysqli_connect(DB_HOST, DB_USER, DB_PASSWORD, DB_DATABASE);
if (mysqli_connect_errno()){
    echo "Failed to connect to MySQL: " . mysqli_connect_error();
 }
mysqli_query($link, "SET NAMES 'utf8';");

function clean($str) {
$str = @trim($str);
if(get_magic_quotes_gpc()) {
    $str = stripslashes($str);
}
return mysqli_real_escape_string($link, $str);
}

$SmjestajGPS = clean( $_POST['SmjestajGPS'] );
```

I got this error:

```
Warning: mysqli_real_escape_string() expects parameter 1 to be mysqli, null given in /home/ninpriva/public_html/admin/smjestaj-obrada.php on line 17
OK
```

But when I go this way I have no error:

```
$SmjestajGPS = mysqli_real_escape_string($link, $_POST['SmjestajGPS'] );
```

Comment: congratulations! You managed to ask one of the most popular questions of Stack overflow!

Comment: Wouldn't you also get a notice about `$link` being undefined in the functions scope?

Comment: I wonder why is error only in fuction?

Comment: Stop wondering, and go read up on _basics_ instead: http://www.php.net/manual/en/language.variables.scope.php

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Clean should be rewritten to look like this:

```
function clean($link, $str) {
    $str = trim($str);
    if (get_magic_quotes_gpc()) {
       $str = stripslashes($str);
    }
    return mysqli_real_escape_string($link, $str);
}

$SmjestajGPS = clean($link, $_POST['SmjestajGPS']);
```